# Primefaces drag drop items between lists

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

Can someone tell me what is the way to make a feature that will allow drag and drop between multiple lists with Primefaces. I want to be able to exchange(drag and drop) items between 4-5 lists. If possible i would like to use pick list because it supports reordering. 
it should be like this: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#empty-lists but using only primefaces/jsf/jstl

Comment: i would guess the football showcase is somewhat close, but guess you have already seen it: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/droppableBarca.jsf

Comment: yeah i have seen it but that's not really what i need. thanks anyway :)

Comment: What about this one http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndTable.jsf

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of options http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/orderList.jsf